# Measuring distance between communities in weighted undirected graph

Tags: r, graph, cluster-analysis, igraph, graph-theory

I have a weighted, undirected graph and there are non-overlapping communities in it. What kind of measurement can help us find out the distance between adjacent communities?

R code below:

```
library(igraph)
# Get a graph
my_graph <- graph("Zachary")
# Run community detection algorithm
my_cluster <- cluster_louvain(my_graph)
# Plot the graph
plot(g, vertex.color = my_cluster$membership)
```

Example: [image: Graphical output here]

In this example, the **Blue** cluster has 3 adjacent communities (**Yellow**, **Green** and **Orange**). From a visual perspective I am convinced that:

- ***Yellow*** is most connected to Blue
- ***Green*** is less connected to Blue
- ***Orange*** is apparently the least connected to Blue...

But what measurements are available to quantify these?

Answer (score 0):

You can define one yourself, whatever makes most sense for your domain. Typical choices combine

1. Some aggregate function: min, max, mean
2. Some per-point measurement: shortest path, longest path, average distance to the other community
3. Some balancing term to adjust for community size & to make the measure symmetric.

For exampleñ

0.5*(mean_a mean_b d(a,b) + mean_b mean_a d(b,a))